# Format on save Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, key-bindings, powercommands

There was an add-on called Power Commands (Now productivity power tools) in visual studio to format the code on save.

I was so used to see my code format on save that I cannot change that habit. Is there a way to do that in Eclipse?

I can only assign one thing to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> otherwise because if I assign `Save` & `Format Code` to the same keys, once I press the shortcut it will do neither but propose me what I want to do with the shortcut. Is there an add-on or a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to

```
Window > Preferences
```

then to

```
Java > Editor > Save actions
```

and tick `Perform the selected actions on save`, then tick `Format source code`

You can also let eclipse perform `Additional actions` which you can freely configure.

Comment: Nice, built in! Thanks lot.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can do that in your `eclipse workspace`. Set your own custom save actions.

Here is what you need to do. [image] 
Navigate to Window --> Preferences, Search for Save in it. and enable the `Perform Selected actions on Save` checkbox.